# Is there an MSE-like site that is more pleasant to work in? Or are there other solutions?

Tags: discussion, deletion, policy

**The Problem:** It becomes more difficult to help people on a site in which there is mass closing of questions.  And I am disturbed that a small group of people is engaged in trying to delete permanently some of the questions I have answered. I interpret it as systematic deliberate erasure of my work.

In my opinion, things have substantially worsened over the past several months. If there seems to be no sign of change, one solution is to scale back my participation on MSE, possibly to nearly zero.

**The question:** Are there suggestions about alternate sites that one could contribute to? Or are there other solutions?

Comment: The deletion aspect is a bug in the system in my opinion, and should be addressed and removed by the developers. But I hope you also can see that others feel that not enough questions are closed, and that the temptation to answer questions sometimes leads to questions being answered when they should be improved by the asker first. In other words, although I am sure that many people participate on this site to help others, there is not agreement on what it means to help with a particular kind of question, and there will likely always be a range of opinions about it.

Comment: My understanding is that a question cannot be deleted if there is an upvoted answer. If that's right, then those who do not wish to see user 6312 scale back know what to do.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It can't be auto-deleted by the community user, but closed questions can be deleted by three 10k+ users (subject to some minor conditions, IIRC).

Comment: I, for one, would hate to see you go.  I am curious: If the rate of closure of questions remained the same, **yet** the system was changed so that the (near-unilateral) deletions ceased, would your desire to leave change?

Comment: @T.Bongers, yes, quite correct; but I think what 6312 is referring to is the effort to get the community user to auto-delete questions by downvoting answers. If I've misunderstood, then, my apologies to all.

Comment: I too am very interested to learn about existing alternatives. I've already scaled back my participation (alas, recently there are far fewer opportunities to  teach  due to the massive closures and deletions). The site has grown to be quite boring and frustrating from a teacher's perspective.

Comment: @Gerryy Upvoting doesn't help when the deletions are caused by 10K users (vs. Community). And recently that has occurred frequently, and seemingly at an increasing pace. In any case the problem has more to do with closure than deletions. If the site continues to reduce the opportunities to teach, it will continue to alienate teachers. These problems could all be fixed if SE provided powerful filtering tools, so people see only the questions that interest them.

Comment: @Bill, "Upvoting doesn't help when the deletions are caused by 10K users...." Yes, Bongers pointed that out, and I acknowledged it. "In any case the problem has more to do with closure than deletions." I read OP's complaint as being more about deletions than closures, and that's what I responded to. "These problems could all be fixed if SE provided powerful filtering tools...." Yes, you've noted that before. So, 1) how do we bring that day about? and 2) what do we do while we're waiting for that day to arrive?

Comment: As far as the original question is concerned: An answer here lists the mathematical fora I am aware of: [Useful mathematical fora](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95787/useful-mathematical-fora). Discussions of mathematics on Reddit (which I am not familiar with) and [Quora](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/quora-vs-stack-exchange-when-asking-about-mathematics) (which I have tried a little) have been mentioned on meta.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Math discussions on reddit are iffy at best; there are some occasional teaching opportunities on /r/learnmath and similar subreddits, but /r/math explicitly prohibits homework-style questions.

Comment: Deletions by 10k users can be overturned by other 10k users, so why this drama? Having said that I don't agree with the votes to close this thread. By now we are relatively well informed about where people stand on the issue of closures of low-quality questions. Deletions not so much.

Comment: For my part I have probably participated in more closures and deletions lately (in comparison to may be a year ago). This is largely because the "on hold -queue" tends to be longer than it was. The increase of delete votes is very recent. The decision to burninate the HW tag brought about the need to deal with hundreds of questions with no other tags. Needless to say, those were probably at the low end of the HW question spectrum. I did carefully look at each question and its answers before casting a delete vote.

Comment: @andre About how many questions you contributed to were deleted (if you know offhand)? Seeing your prolificness and the obvious drive behind it, you have a lot of room to scale down if you need to, in order not to burn out. By all means, take a breather every now and then, and remember that whatever you do get around to doing is appreciated :)

Comment: I am replying to the first sentence only. Too many were downvoted by you-know-who or clones in obvious preparation for automatic system deletion. There is a systematic campaign, of which this is not the only sign, to remove many questions, and as collateral damage to erase the work of others.

Comment: I am rather against closures on meta, but the question asked has nothing whatsoever to do with this site, it is about any site but this one. Moreover it is *extremely* subjective. On top of that the surrounding text it is full of self-indulgence.

Comment: To make a beautiful sculpture, you start with a hunk of rock, and remove everything that isn't a beautiful sculpture.

Comment: @Hurkyl To make a beautiful mathematical mind, one often starts with a hopelessly confused student, who has no clue where to begin.

Comment: @quid, it is true that the question, "Are there suggestions about alternate sites that one could contribute to?" is not a question about m.se and is thus a better fit for m.se than for this meta site. But taking the post as a whole I'm in no doubt that meta is exactly where it belongs.

Comment: Please don't leave.

Comment: I'm sorry if any deletion votes I've cast have had a negative impact on your goal of teaching here, @André. I think the site would have a terrible loss if you were to leave.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In principle, this posts really belongs nowhere, since it is a self-indulgent rant. But, as said, I am pretty open to have many things on meta(s); I did not mean to call for its closure I did not even dv. However, I felt to make explicit that the question asked is not a question to be asked here, to counter claims that votes to close (necessarily) are trying to supress some opinion. They simply could be cast, since when taken seriously the post is off-topic. But, as said, I know the post should not be taken seriously (or perhaps 'at face value' is the better expression).

Comment: The question appears to be more of a way to make the statement "I am considering leaving the site for these reasons" than an actual question. Even so, the question being asked is, in my opinion, off topic.

Comment: @CarlMummert You've mentioned that you believe the deletion loophole to be a simple bug.  At the detriment of my Meta.SE reputation, I believe I have determined this [not to be the case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237469/201314).

Comment: @anorton: thanks for the link. I have a peculiar meaning when I say something is a bug. I would not be surprised if the devs disagee with me. And, although I think it is unfortunate for one user to be able to delete other's answers, I do agree with someone on the linked thread that unless we want this site to be MathHomework.SE we need to hold questions to a higher standard *regardless whether we know that they are homework*. In some cases, the answers being deleted probably should have been reserved until the OP improved the question - which is a separate issue from the deletion bug.

Comment: Regarding the offtopicness of this question, I'll come out and say it. André leaving concerns the main site very much. He's the user with the most reputation and he gives answer on a very broad set of topics. I'm thinking of André as a tool. The question here addresses the possibility of losing this very prolific tool.

Comment: @GitGud Saying of someone that  he is a tool  is not very nice. More to the point, threads about people leaving site are regularly closed with the formulation that "users leaving the site is their own damn business". Let's not have double standards here. André Nicolas, your decision to stay or go is your own damn business.

Comment: @GitGud: The word "tool" has several connotations that make it best to avoid applying to people, to avoid unintended deprecation.  I understand the intent, but I think this is distracting.  (Sorry I don't have a good alternative phrasing.)

Comment: @900sit-upsaday I'm not disagreeing about the "tool" comment, but an important difference between this and the questions about users leaving the site is that this question *was started* by the person who may leave, and it's *not* asking about why the person left.

Comment: @900: As someone who fiercely votes down and votes to close threads asking about other user's reasons for leaving, this thread is different. Whether or not it's off topic, is a different story on which I haven't made up my mind.

Comment: Drats! Please tell me that we are not, yet again, about to lose another one of our great MSE heroes. @AndréNicolas I think we are stuck with this, the rest just kinda suck even worse. I will quietly remain here mostly silenced, but grateful that it exists. The recent winds of change by a few do however break my heart a bit though, I must admit.

Comment: Honestly, the more time I read meta the more I want to see a good alternative to this site. A person who has poured as much effort, time and expert insight as the OP ought to be a bit more respected by users whose main claim to fame is being glorified internet janitors. At the university, when you see someone write on the board, "do not erase" you leave it alone and respect their work. The same basic principle ought to apply here.

Comment: I have the utmost admiration and respect for AndreNicolas and his work in this site.  I know nothing about the problem he complains about (in the body of his rant, and in his comment about the "systematic campaign"), might be he is right or not. But the title and -what he calls- "The question:" are out of place.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook the analogy is a bit strange. But, frankly, I would be curious to know what happens in actual reality should somebdoy leave the blackboards of a lecture hall full and with a "do not erase." Do you actually believe this would be respected just like this no questions asked (on a regular basis) by those using the room afterwards? I'd say you can do this with your private blackboard in your office, yet doing it with a shared one (on a regular basis) is quite rude.

Comment: @quid if there were 311,000 or so existing blackboards and a nearly limitless supply of future boards then yes, in reality, I doubt anyone would be bothered if I left "do not erase" for the remainder of my physical existence.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook you wrote that "At the university" something would happoen. So what would actually happen at a university? That your analogy is strange since there is no analogy of the situations was pointed out by me. But you brought it up. Either use an analogy or don't. But if you do it, it needs to make at least some sense. I will take your flippant reply as evidence that the analogy was misplaced.

Comment: @James S. Cook: I bet it would be really annoying if your "do not erase" was on the first blackboard in the row of available ones.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen "Deletions by 10k users can be overturned by other 10k users, so why this drama?"
How do you detect a deleted question?

Comment: Perhaps the suggestion is that one could regularly go through one's answers (I have more than $9000$) looking for deletions, and undo these.

Comment: @Deep, the idea is to go to the `/tools` page, there to the "delete" tab, and check the "Recently Deleted" and "Undelete votes" queues whether something merits undeletion. And the "Delete votes" queue to see what of that needs to be deleted.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: If we extrapolate your analogy a bit, this thread is in a way about the said professor threatening to quit, because his "Do not erase" request is not honored in $0.25$ % of the cases. You are new to Meta (good for you in many ways, trust me), but you haven't been exposed to many facets of this divisive issue. It would be sad if André left. Many others already have. We can only speculate about their reasons. Some may have felt like André, some may have left for the opposite reason that they don't want to be associated with a homework factory. How high would those teachers be ..

Comment: For *ones own* recent answers it seems trivial to check if some were deleted. There is a *page* for exactly this http://math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/N (with N to be replaced by ones usernumber). Same exists for questions. All claims that things get deleted somewhat quickly and noone can notice in a reasonable way are *simply false*. (There is still the issue of old content and one could say one should be more careful there, but then if content did not get any posiitve feedback for an extended period of time, namely 2 months, perhaps it is not that important after all.)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I confess that I am shocked by some of the things proposed above. I find it absolutely absurd that one should have to waste precious time searching through obscure lists to find one's contributions that were destroyed by other users, and then waste further time trying to rally other users to restore such content. This is certainly *not* "much healthier". It is in fact the the most toxic tumor that I have ever seen infect any general level math forum. If this continues I will certainly leave, and will strongly encourage others to stay clear of the infected site.

Comment: Indeed, this Crusade is becoming woefully toxic, and the Great Crusader (and recruited clones), wearing the banner of working to make the site "much healthier" on behalf of "us all", is delusional, and worse, pretending "they" represent/speak for the community. This is an extremely contentious matter. I am deeply offended when *anyone* presupposes to speak for the community, and perceives his/her thoughts, opinions, evaluations, and commitments to be unilaterally "right", and anyone who disagrees, wrong. This is, indeed, a good time to consider alternatives.

Comment: @amWhy:  You have set a very high standard of respectfulness to those who ask questions, one that because of temperament I cannot hope to emulate, but that still serves as a guide.

Comment: @amWhy Who presupposes to speak for the community? At least the user I have reasons to believe you refer to as "the Great Crusader" (which can be seen as pretty offensive in various ways, but okay) made it extremly clear that they act following their opinion and believes only, for example: ["Voting is not by consensus, it is everyone's expression of their own opinion." or "No, it is still just an opinion of one user, who happens to think that those Q&As should be deleted."](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16469/) But, some others do not like this either.

Comment: In case anyone would take it seriously, I want to mention that Bill Dubuque has threatened to leave the site many times, for years.

Comment: @Jonas fyi: I did leave in the past. And this matter is *far* more serious than the matters that alienated me in the past. This time I think it may well be a mass exodus. There may well be no 100K+ users left if the site continues on this destructive course.

Comment: Half of the 100k+ users have either left or talked about leaving due to differences on site politics. That goes to show how poorly we've done at reaching compromises on contentious matters. The latest mass deletion campaign is a perfect example: initiated secretly without any prior discussion, or any attempt to reach a compromise based on rational discussion of the diverse positions in the community.

Comment: @BillDubuque If you did not notice there was a proposal for a compromise in this very thread: those that answer, or to use your wording the teachers, also take care of the question if they are poor quality. What's wrong with that? Doing this might then also allow you to upvote questions you answer at a rate higher than (at most, likely lower) 1 in 8 or something like that. (Thinking about it, you ought to agree most of the question you answer are not overly good.)

Comment: @Bill: I think you are simply wrong in that this was initiated by something. 900's actions may have triggered a few things. But the burnination of the HW tag made it a civic duty to dig thru hundreds of poor old questions, and this brought about a wider participation in the deletion business. The point is that the resentment towards low quality questions has been brewing for a long time. The unwillingness of the "it is my inalienable right to answer any question I choose" -party to agree to any kind of a compromise left others powerless. Now that we were familiarized with a few tools

Comment: (cont'd) the resentment built up over the years may be erupting. Ok, so I'm a drama queen again, but that's how it seems to me. With the clean up soon complete I predict that deletion rate will calm down quite a bit. But it probably will not go back to the old ultra-low level. I hope that eventually some kind of an equilibrium is reached.

Comment: @Jyrki  My concern has little to do with removing the homework tag. Rather it has to do with the massive deletion of helpful answers (as we recently discussed), esp. answers which may play key roles in a large network of linked posts.

Comment: @Bill: I've yet to see any of these mythical "helpful answers" that have been deleted, yet alone any indication that such things are anything other than rare mistakes that could be rectified individually.

Comment: @Hurkyl Have you looked? I've seen many. You have to check a few times per day because they quickly disappear due to the fixed size of the list.

Comment: @Bill: Generally, when someone wants me to believe something, I expect them to show me reasons why I should believe, rather than believing by default until I find my own reasons to disbelieve. That said, over a half dozen deleted questions have been linked so far, apparently as examples of what we're losing, and there weren't any helpful answers among those.

Comment: I disagree with the use of *helpful* as a criterion. A merely helpful answer to a bad question does not make a quality combination.

Comment: @Hurkyl I don't know any easy way to relocate them since they are long gone off the very short list of deletions that is made available in the 10K tools. Yet another biased part of the SE design, which makes it extremely easy to surreptitiously delete things, but extremely difficult to even notice/find the deletions, let alone try reverse them. This is even worse than the close/reopen bias in the early days (before there were queues, and before I created the meta reopen request thread to try to help restore some balance).

Comment: I found the recently deleted list. Checked the most recent 10 deleted things today. A handful of "homework - suggestion" interactions, but none were particularly remarkable or had lasting value.

Comment: @Hurkyl Was this the first time you found the /tools page? :) Better late than never, then. The major reason the close-delete pipeline is broken is the lack of concerted effort of 10K users.

Comment: @900: I've seen it before, but at the times there had been nothing interesting to me, so I forgot about them.

Comment: @AndréNicolas http://mathhelpforum.com/   Pros: Site has less attitude. Cons: Site is less polished than SE. You don't get reputation points, you can't downvote or delete posts. It's strictly question and answer...

Comment: @user137481: Thank you, I will look. Since I have not downvoted on MSE since $2012$, there would be no withdrawal symptoms on that score.

Comment: @Bill: If we have a systemic problem of good answers getting deleted, I would imagine you could find fresh examples in the list, rather than having to search through all of history. If this can't be done, then this reinforces my current opinion that the bulk of the deletions are fine, and any problems are rare occurrences.

Comment: Looked at 10 again. Spam. Assigned geometry problem, unmotivated solution. Stats problem, with explanation that insufficient information was given. Verify my homework problem with mostly yes/no answers. Optimization problem asked, answer points out an algebraic trick that was missed. 2 * routine "do my homework" "okay". Another "do my homework", with "the problem's wrong". Another "do my homework" (but this time with "it's due tomorrow!"), answer is yet another exposition of "stars and bars" works. Another "do my combinatorics homework", with an answer "here's how to do base 3 arithmetic".

Comment: Incidentally, I'm ambivalent about the answer to [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/197856/14972) (the question still sucks). But if someone wants to salvage the answer, there's *surely* an abstract duplicate about "counting numerals subject to a condition" somewhere. But I doubt the answer there really has anything that you couldn't find in the answers to any of the other questions. (except for the rehash of 3's complement ternary arithmetic)

Comment: @Hurkyl The last couple days are markedly different than the prior massive deletions (perhaps because the new homework tag compaign has made it impossible to see the answers deleted by 900, because the queue is not long enough to hold both). As you may have noticed, I had already voted to undelete that answer of Brian.

Comment: @Bill: So while you assert things had been problematic, things are okay now?

Comment: Re the *question by David* you have voted to undelete, do you have a plan once it gets undeleted? e.g. do you have an edit in mind to improve it? That could be done *now*, I believe.

Comment: I'm not sure things can be made good without making significant edits to the answer, though, since the answer is answering two very different and unrelated questions. ("what is 3's complement ternary notation?" and "how do you count numerals subject to constraints?")

Comment: @Hurkyl Since I have no way to easily see the *entire* list of deleted questions, there is no way to assess much. It overflowed in 3 hours last night, so who knows how many deleted questions were not displayed (the 10k Tools list  is limited to 45 entries). It didn't overflow so quickly in the past. Perhaps the increased volume is due to the recent homework tag removal.

Comment: @Bill: I'm not asking you to certify that there wasn't a single gem deleted in the bunch, just that that is a pretty rare phenomenon, and that only needs a reasonable sample.

Comment: @Hurkyl As I said, there is no easy way to relocate them, since they are long gone off the list, which last night overlfowed in 3 hrs.

Comment: @Bill: I'm pretty sure there's a reasonable sampling strategy that isn't thwarted by the list overflowing in 3 hours. :P For example, I'm going to spend a few days looking at the last 10 deletions, and hopefully I'll manage to sample from diverse times. If I see nothing I find problematic, I will be pretty confident that problems are rather rare.

Comment: @Hurkyl If the Community User deletions each night are more than 45 then it wlll not be possible to see all of them, no matter how one samples the list.

Comment: @Bill: When I say sample, I really do mean [sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_(statistics)) and not "look at everything".

Comment: @Hurkyl When it comes to deletion of site content, I think it is *essential* to keep a close eye on such, because it could easily be abused to discriminate against certain types of content, and could easily be hidden by employing scheduling that exploits the fixed length of the list - just as other SE weaknesses have been exploited in the massive deletion campaign.

Comment: @Bill: Just to be clear, you are essentially agreeing with the hypothesis that the deletions appearing on the list are, by an large, fine and proper? And that (aside from the rare exceptions) your worries about the future loss of good answers are limited to the case where good answers are *specifically singled out* from the rest of the deletions so that they happen in a way that is completely invisible?

Comment: @hurkyl Of course I do *not* agree with what *you* wrote. Since you don't seem to be reading what *I* wrote, I will not waste any further time replying.

Comment: @Bill: If the deletions *appearing on the list* are are *not*, by and large, fine and proper, then I refer you back to my claim that you should be able to find examples by sampling the list.

Comment: @Hurkyl I've already explained that *twice*. I will not do it again. You've long ago exhausted my patience.

Comment: @Bill: Fine. I've spent over an hour now trying to be open to the possibility that you have a legitimate objection and trying to pin down its nature (which includes understanding what you are *not* objecting to) and how to observe if problems are still ongoing problem. I'm no longer inclined to pursue this.

Comment: I share André's frustration. If I think I can guess what a question is about, I'm happy to try to answer it. If other people regard the question as "unclear", I think that's sometimes a sign that they have the wrong background (e.g. pure mathematics, rather than computing), or they're just not very sympathetic towards a struggling student. If your native language is not English, or you have little training in formal mathematics, it's very difficult to phrase questions in the "proper" mathematical way. We can either show some sympathy and kindness, or we can exclude people. I prefer the former.

Comment: The "lasting value" discussion is disturbing. When I answer a question, I don't kid myself that I'm contributing to some grand archival repository of mathematical knowledge. I'm happy if I can just help the OP understand something that was puzzling him (or her). We're just answering people's questions; we're not writing the on-line encyclopedia of mathematics (or, at least, I'm not).

Comment: Is there a more pleasant site?? I don't know. Maybe we could find out where Brian Scott went. Brian, Andre, Bill, amWhy, and a  few of the other like-minded folks from around here would be a good nucleus for a new site.

Comment: @bubba: I agree with you that there are many questions put on hold because the voters lacked the background to assess the difficulty (or the point) of the question (and thus the WHYT-comments rang hollow). That's is why I promoted [this approach](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10962/11619). But do give people here some credit. I don't recall having had problems getting such questions reopened. I very much doubt that it is at the core of this dispute.

Comment: @bubba re "lasting value":  I can in some sense connect to the view you have yet there is one thing that is now *very* unclear to me. What exactly is then the problem with the *deletions*? OP typical had more than enough time to read the answer before any deletions happen (and AFAIK can even see it after deletion for a long time). The deletion should be a nonissue when one takes your view.

Comment: @quid -- Answers might still have some lasting value even if they are not worthy of inclusion in the Grand Repository. To be honest, I don't know whether I have yet been a victim of the purge, but I'm sure I would be annoyed if someone decided to delete something that I put effort into writing. I'd find it insulting and demotivating. It's an emotional response, granted, but that doesn't make it any less real. It would make me want to write stuff somewhere else, rather than here.

Comment: It becomes more difficult to improve this site when there is a small, disturbing group of people actively engaged in trying to keep the site in the gutter. I too am feeling frustrated, possibly enough to quit MSE again.

Comment: @DanielFischer "the idea is to go to the /tools page, there to the "delete" tab, and check the "Recently Deleted" and "Undelete votes" queues whether something merits undeletion."
I guess a problem is that most users don't bother doing it.

Comment: @Deep Right. Most users don't bother (well, most don't even have access to it yet, one needs 10K). I admit that I was too lazy to do it too until the hubbub started. And actually it's a very rare occasion that something merits undeletion.

Comment: @DanielFischer That you think it doesn't merit undeletion is your subjective opinion and it's very unlikely that you are conversant with every field of mathematics(correct me if my guess is wrong).
Please notice that this site accepts any level(elementary or advanced) of mathematical questions.
Moreover judging from what you wrote, you don't check deleted questions or answers very often.
In other words, I think your samples are too small to conclude that deleted questions or answers which are mathematically valuable are rare.

Comment: @Deep to bring up being conversant with every field of mathematics rather suggests that you do not really have much of an idea what the discussion is about.

Comment: @quid Just wondering: do you re-check  all these long comment threads one by one, or are you using some browser extension for them (like my *Comments in Sidebar*)?

Comment: @quid My point is that a user is unlikely to be able to evaluate a question or an answer properly if he is not conversant with the field to which it belongs.

Comment: @Deep Of course it's subjective opinion, I thought that goes without saying. Whether I check often depends on what you call often. On most days, since the meta explosion, I check the lists several times. No, I'm not on speaking terms with every field, but most deletions affect fields with which I am acquainted enough to pass a moderately reasonable judgment concerning the value. Threads on algebraic geometry for example seem to rarely be deleted. I'd have trouble judging the value of answers beyond the elementary there, but so far the need hasn't arisen.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday the former.

Comment: @quid What a waste of time. Get the [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/comments-in-sidebar/fojkncjknkcndbglhlfaenlkngflapeb) already. Free for the first 30 days of use. And also after that.

Comment: @Deep well, yes. But, as Daniel Fischer also explained in the interim, almost all of the deleted questions should belong to a pretty small segment of maths.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Yes I should optimize my worklflow, or perhaps still better just ignore some things. :-)

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think the issue is that there are different opinions of what MSE should be. There are some who don't have any issues with "homework" and then there are those who don't think MSE should not "do their homework". A better alternative to leaving would be to get together with like-minded people (e.g. Bill Dubuque) and propose another site to Stack Exchange. Of course, the new site would have to have a constitution that specifically forbid the type of behaviour that led to this post...  8-)

Comment: The problem here is your misunderstanding that this is some kind of a "help site". It is not.

Comment: Since its inception, the site has helped people, including students, solve problems. The "homework" tag has been the most common one, and a majority of homework questions, particularly at the mid-undergraduate or higher level, were not so tagged.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I find your comment unclear, perhaps because I don't know your definition of "help site".  What does that mean?  People ask questions here because they (at least) want help answering them, right?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217130/155739

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why do you think that some random answer on some other SE site has anything to do with policy matters on this site?

Comment: @BillDubuque: Stack Exchange policy is for all of Stack Exchange. Your Stack Exchange subsite is not "special" nor does it have the magical right to ignore network-wide policy. That "random answer" on "some other SE site" is on meta.SE, the place where policy for all of Stack Exchange is decided, and I linked it so that I did not have to repeat myself. I concede that there is a typo in the answer, which says "Stack Overflow" rather than "Stack Exchange". Thanks for being a part of the wider Stack Exchange community.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Since you have almost zero activity here, you may not be aware that we are quite different from most SE sites, and many of our policies do differ from generic SE policies. In any case, what is the point of participating in a meta discussion on a site that you have very little familiarity with?

Comment: @BillDubuque: Just because I don't post doesn't mean I have "very little familiarity", or "zero activity". Check your privilege. Again, you can't just "decide" you won't follow SE rules because you don't like them. If you don't like it, start a new site.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You have *infinitessimal* activity here (one answer on main about a joke, and a few comments). You can't possibly be familiar with the unique issues challenging this site. Drive-by opinions are very rarely helpful.

Comment: @BillDubuque: You didn't actually read my comment, did you? Or perhaps you read it, but did not understand it, as seems increasingly likely from your evident tendency to resort to rude messages when you don't get your way. You've never heard of _lurking_? And, for the final time, _activity on this particular SE subsite is utterly irrelevant_ anyway when discussing network-wide policies. I'm not sure why you're having such a hard time with this concept.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I'll come back when you've stopped arrogantly belittling my input based on things you know nothing about ("drive-by opinions" is not very nice), and when you've figured out that Stack Exchange is one network. If I've done far more lurking on math.SE than posting, this sort of childish discourse is precisely why, Bill.

Comment: @Lightness I suspect that you are working under the assumption that your knowledge of generic SE recommendations (and your high activity on another site) implies that your meta knowledge should transfer to this site. I don't agree with that. In fact one of the founders of SE (Jeff Atwood) remarked a number of times about how difficult it was to understand this site. *General-level* math forums are *very unique beasts.* Always have been and always will be - no matter what platform currently supports them.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I've already addressed that. You're trying to add some magic powers to Math.SE, and your description of it as a "forum" just confirms that. _No Stack Exchange site is a "forum"._ None of them. No matter how much of a "unique beast" you may think you are.

Comment: @Lightness I simply pointed out some facts about the history of this site. I used the term "general-level math forums" because it is a suitable generic term to include this site, sci.math, etc. Don't read more in to it than what was intended. I'm afraid we'll have to agree to disagree on the uniqueness aspects. I've participated heavily in such "forums" for a few decades, so my observations are quite well-founded.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Participation in "forums" is irrelevant to discussion on _this_ network of websites (which are not forums), no matter how many _decades_ you wish to bring into it to make yourself sound authoritative. Wasn't "experience elsewhere is not experience here" an argument that _you_ tried to use, just a moment ago? Sigh. We can at least agree that this is going nowhere. All the best.

Comment: @Lightness As I said, "general-level math forum" includes *this* site, so your remark makes no sense. I have no interest in arguing with you about the definition of "forum". Let's simply agree to disagree.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I don't know how many times I need you tell you that Stack Exchange sites are not forums. This is widely and well known across the entire network. You're the only high-rep user I've ever met who doesn't grok it.

Comment: @Lightness That we (clearly) disagree on the definition of the overloaded term "forum" has little import here.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: "Your Stack Exchange subsite is not "special" nor does it have the magical right to ignore network-wide policy."  I agree with some things you write, but that quoted statement is not really correct. We can indeed ignore many "network-wide policies", if such things even exist.  For example, we make our own rules on which questions are acceptable, which should be closed, whether problem statement questions are on-topic, etc.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I will also point out that the issue of "helping one person" versus "permanent record for Google" may not be the best way to frame the issue here, because one complaint seems to be that *too many questions are being deleted from Google even if the OP was already helped*.  I think people on both sides think that what they advocate is the best way to "help" the OP.

Comment: @Carl: It's more like "too many questions are being deleted from Google even though the OP was already helped", which is a disingenuous observation because one single OP being helped is indeed not the purpose of the site.

Comment: This in response to amWhy's comment of 7 August:  It bugs me too when people speak for the site membership as a whole.  I see an increasing number of comments which introduce themselves with phrasing like, "Welcome to math.se.  *WE* would appreciate it if you learned a little $\LaTeX$ etc etc etc" (put your favorite critical remarks here).  My impulse is to respond to such "We" comments with "You and who else?"  But I have managed to restrain myself from sarcasm so far.  How long will I hold out until I detonate?  Who knows . . .

Comment: I further observe an increasing number of newer members (say under 1000 rep. or less than 3 months here) adopting such behaviors; this though disconcerting comes as no surprise:  kids learn from their elders, students from their teachers, newer members from old; they look and see more experienced users respond a certain way and it's, "that must be the way to fit it", "*that's* the local culture"; but these tendencies have been around since before monkeys became men.  And yes, I am a Darwinian!  My name's Bob; thanks for letting me share . . .

Comment: Can I award a bounty to a question?

Answer (score 37):

I haven't been here long, and I rarely follow meta.  That said, I am surprised and dismayed by what I perceive to be very open hostility among several prominent users here, over something that I consider to be not particularly significant--"contributions" to a site.

No single user, no matter how high their reputation or extensive their contribution to MSE, should feel entitled to the ownership of such contributions.  This site is not an academic publication.  Whatever content you post here is understood to be freely given and subject to modification or deletion.  If that doesn't suit you, then you are more than welcome to compile your knowledge in other, perhaps more traditional, ways.  To that end, I cannot suggest any internet site that meets such a standard, for the internet is paradoxical in that, once put online, some things never go away; yet things are easily lost to intrinsic impermanence.

Regarding the nature of closure and deletion, I find that the role of MSE should not, in my view, merely be that of a homework-answering service.  Questions that do not show any problem-solving effort on the part of the submitter are extremely common, and I believe that if these are not addressed in a uniform manner, such behavior becomes encouraged to the point that it will overwhelm the site entirely.  One might argue that it is not our responsibility to police students and discourage them from cheating, unethical behavior, or at the very least, the failure to appreciate the value of self-learning.  One might also argue that if they do not get their questions answered here, they would simply turn elsewhere (and they frequently do).  But all I can say is that for my own personal conscience, I would feel ill at ease if I did not vote to close a question that I perceived as being asked in bad faith.  That doesn't mean I am perfect at sorting it out, but that lack of perfect discernment does not mean an acceptable solution is to not attempt to draw a distinction at all.

And if others do not have such qualms, it is not my place to tell them that they should.

The system here is quite democratic:  for the most part, each of us gets as much influence or voice as we ought to.  What does not sit well with me is the idea that just because some people have very high reputation counts and a long posting history, that they can dictate to everyone else the direction this site should go--with thinly veiled threats.  That, to me, seems juvenile and self-centered.  We each contribute **freely**.  That doesn't make any one person's contributions more worthy than another's.  If your contributions get deleted because some users in the community are collectively deciding that this site should enforce a policy of not actively assisting parasitic behavior, that is unfortunate, but surely cannot be cause for complaint that "your" work is being lost:  you cannot lose what you **gave away**.  You are always welcome to not give away your knowledge, but to suggest in such a retaliatory fashion that you somehow "deserve" better treatment is not particularly mature.

Comment: I agree with your basic principle of that you don't have ownership to the answers that you post here, but you are forgetting that besides the formal aspects there are also personal aspects to this matter. In this case, the number 1 contributing user to this site (and other high repusers) who does not feel happy because apparently a *significant* amount of his answers were deleted. Then of course you can point him to these principles, but you have to understand that this does not motivate someone to keep answering on this site, however  right you may formally be.

Comment: @dreamer The "significant amount" would be less than 0.5%, from what I remember having seen deleted. I'd estimate it at about 0.1%.

Comment: @DanielFisher I trust that you're right, but if it concerns so little questions I *cannot* believe that we can't simply edit those questions. I'm solely thinking in terms of what is more useful for the site, and I still think that this is not the right thing to do.

Comment: @dreamer Editing bad questions into something that one could keep is hard work. One only makes that effort if one thinks the answers to the question are worth it.

Comment: I do agree with you.

Comment: @dreamer It should be recognized that some would appreciate if *certain types of* questions were *not* answered. It is thus not at all a problem if the motivation to answer these types of questions would decrease.

Comment: @quid Well I think that it is obvious from the OP that not only the motivation to answer *these* kind of questions dissapears.

Comment: @dreamer this is posisble, but perhaps not the most rational way to approach the issue.

Comment: @dreamer There is no shortage of users on this site who are willing to answer well-asked questions that demonstrate original effort.  The number of high-reputation users who answer anything and everything without regard to ethics because they regard this site as a race to accrue reputation, is small.  I doubt they would so easily leave given their addiction to posting, but even if they did, they would not be missed.  The site would be better for it because it would no longer encourage homework answering.

Answer (score 17):

Since the question has been expanded to include other solutions, I'll propose one:

- Improve the questions whose current state **puts your answers at risk**

Here is a query that finds them:
[**My answers at risk**](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/214021/my-answers-at-risk?UserId=6312), with your UserId pre-filled. It locates the answers that may be deleted if you-know-who downvotes them and/or the question.

There are $25$ results right now, representing $0.25\%$ of your answers. These are closed (not as duplicates), have score at most $1$, the question has score at most $1$, and there is no accepted answer.

Sure, some of them can be saved from the evil downvoter with an upvote. But it *might* be better  to improve the question. A question can be improved by adding some context:

#### Context

This problem is of the kind ... which are usually solved with ... This one is particularly (hard|nice) because ...

This will add information for both the OP and for future readers. It will also set a better example for future question askers.

Comment: To be fair, I ran the same query for myself: it brought up two answers (which by the way, is also $\approx 0.25\%$ of all my answers). They might have been helpful at the time, but did not have any lasting value.  I deleted both.

Comment: I have only 5 out of 3500. Did I win?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The new UTC day arrives in 75 minutes, and with it my new batch of downvotes. Don't say you were not warned.

Comment: Well, some of them are illegible for your hammer (by having other high voted answers). Probably just one which is on the edge here, and I'm considering whether or not to delete it or to improve the question.

Comment: Ah, right. I did not check for other higher-voted answers, it would make the query a bit slower, without making much difference in the results. Low-scoring answers to low-scoring closed questions are something to take a look at, anyway.

Comment: ... and I'm out of downvotes already. The danger passed... until the next UTC day.

Comment: I got an empty list. Strange. Many answers I'm not proud of.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Congratulations of having higher standards than many of us...

Comment: @Jyrki: Or on having people vote your answers, or the questions you answered!

Comment: Hmm. Last four pages (about 120 answers) have zero score. About 20 of them accepted. May be I'm just lucky?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Only three of the questions you've answered are currently closed other than duplicates. [These ones](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/213146/closed-non-duplicate-questions-answered-by-a-user?UserId=11619). I don't know how proud you are of these answers, but they are scored 3 or higher. As for answers to non-closed questions, nobody and nothing can delete them until the question is closed; save for moderator action.

Comment: ... which, by the way, is an illustration of how "unilateral" my sneaky deletions really are ... First, five users have to agree to close, then others decide not to vote for reopening, yet others decide not to upvote...

Comment: "not vote to reopen" is not really something that should get in the way here. Not everyone monitors the recently closed list continuously and votes to reopen continuously...

Comment: Two of them are gone. One was of the LMGIFY-type, and the punchline of the other was to quote Göthe. The third (a contest question) can stay. I had voted to reopen [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/578360/11619), but the vote has apparently expired. It's not as sleek as Noam Elkies' answer, but there's a reason why he topped my IMO bronze medals with two gold medals. Also, I'll be damned if I help Putin :-) Voting to delete [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/192672/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I edited the post about the quartic and voted to reopen; it got reopened within about an hour.

Comment: Thanks, @900! Odd that I haven't been hit rep-wise yet from the deletions. I guess that will sort itself soon :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Score $\geqslant 3$, and visible for $\geqslant 60$ days means you keep the rep. That was made so when the wailing about deleted old off-topic but highly-voted threads on Stack Overflow became too loud. Let people keep their internet points, and they only complain about [putative] crap being deleted when they honestly think it isn't crap..

Comment: Thanks for the bit of news @Daniel. Somehow I had managed to miss that. I guess that means that A) I can give more bounties, B) I have less reservations about deleting poor questions.

Comment: @DanielFischer What strange logic behind that design decision. It seems to imply that the SE thinks that rep is more important than the information conveyed in the answer. Why preserve the rep but delete the answer? Are we here to accumulate "rep" or to share mathematical knowledge?

Comment: @BillDubuque The design decision was "We want to get rid of crap, even highly upvoted crap like 'What's your favorite Programmer Cartoon' [not that such a thread is necessarily crap on its own, but in the context and purpose of SO, it is], but every time such a thread is deleted people come to meta and raise a stink, and we get a delete-undelete war. We don't want the latter, so let people keep their rep, then they only complain about deletions of threads they really consider valuable." From a utilitarian standpoint, that makes much sense.

Comment: @Daniel Bizzare. If it *really* is crap, then the rep *should* be lost on deletion.

Comment: "improve the question" ... beginning with this one, I'd say.

Comment: @Dan One possible fix is to require deletions to be approved by n users with sufficient "rep" in the tag(s). Presumably they can better judge the quality of any deleted answers that might be lost. Also the 10K tool histories need to be extended (now its only 12/24 hrs, far too short). Maybe there should be (un)deletion queues too (which do have better history)

Comment: @BillDubuque It's not the time, you have tabs for today, 2d, 7d, 14d, 30d, that should/would be enough. The problem is that there's a [too low] limit on the number of items shown [apparently 45]. There's a feature request to change that. Requiring an approval for every deletion by sufficiently-high-tag-rep users is not a viable option. It could possibly be if enough people looked at the candidates, but people don't, it's not much fun, and takes too much time.

Comment: @Daniel Indeed, I wrote 12 to 24 hours to reflect the typical time limit I saw, since it was not clear what the limiting factor was. Thanks for relaying the info that the limit is a hard limit on the number of items in the list. 45 items is surely too small for a large site like this.

Answer (score 15):

As you may know, moderators have access to certain statistics which aren't otherwise easily visible (though which are largely retrievable from either the SO data dumps or data.se). I have also perceived more closures and deletions than normal, so I thought I'd take a look at the data. We are asked to not share specifics (I don't know why), so these are averages.

It turns out that somewhere between 8% and 9% of posts (questions and answers together) are deleted each week this year - closer to 9% now, closer to 8% in January. Last year, It hovered between 6.5% and 7%. So there is a definite increase. To me, it feels pretty noticeable.

In many ways, I find the SE platform to be well-designed for self-governance. I rarely disagree with people deleting answers - it seems to me that people rarely delete answers without good reason. But some people target some questions (and their answers fall because of it). There are three ways to delete a question (**edit: as is pointed out in the comments, I'm slightly off here. See the comments, but it doesn't change the discussion**):

1. If the question is negatively scored, more than a month old, and there are no upvoted answers, then the Community user will delete the question automatically.
2. A number of users puts the question on hold. If it is not reopened in the next 5 days, the question becomes closed. Once the question is closed, 3 10k users vote to delete.
3. A mod uses mod superpowers to delete the question.

Issues with the first way would be decreased if more people voted. Something that I've noticed much more than closures and deletions is that the voting has not at all kept up with site growth. Unfortunately, while we can sometimes say [vote early, vote often](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/662/vote-early-vote-often), a very small group of users reads the meta and fewer care about what they read - this is very hard to change.

The ideal resolution of the second way is for users to edit their `on hold` question. It gets put in a reopen queue, and users tend to be pretty liberal about reopening after any nontrivial edit from the queue. Frankly, though, users very often don't edit their question. Or if they do, they're confused - they have no idea how to approach the problem, users demand `context`, and they edit something in like `I'm lost. What do I do?`, which typically doesn't lead to reopenings.

Something which could be done, but which isn't done very often, is for capable users of *really* editing lower quality questions into reasonable questions, especially questions that have been otherwise abandoned by the OP. For example, it seems to me that it's extremely likely that an answer of André is great, and the site is better off with it than without. If the question is enroute to being closed, then perhaps a higher rep user could *really* edit the question. [This conforms to the view that this site is a Q&A repository, where good answers to good questions should be kept so that they can be found later; a different popular view is that this site is for learning math, and thus answers should help the OP first and foremost, including limiting to hints and whatnot]

To try to answer your actual question, [Martin's Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95787/useful-mathematical-fora) in the comments contains every site that I know of aside from reddit and quora. I've at least looked at all of them before (and migrated here from mymathforum), and I really think MSE and MO are the best at what they do (i.e. not discussion).

Comment: Correction to Item 2: 10K users can vote to delete  2 days  after closure; they don't have to wait for [on-hold] to turn to [closed]. [Source](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: Item 1 is also incorrect. At the age of 30 days, a question is deleted if it is negatively scored and there are *no answers at all*. In particular, this path does not lead to answers being deleted. You missed another scenario: a  question that's been [on-hold]/closed for 9 days is deleted if there are no positively scored posts in the thread (Q or A).

Comment: Thank you for digging up some stats. I cannot shake the feeling that to some extent the relative increase of closures and deletions reflects the fact (or, perhaps more accurately, a gut feeling) that the growth of the site has largely come from high-schoolers/freshmen wanting somebody to do their homework for them. It is, of course, nearly impossible to substantiate (or disprove) my point. Just felt like bringing it up anyway.

Comment: I have also noticed that @Jyrki Lahtonen mentioned: I have no way to verify it, but I feel as if the average quality of questions has gone down in the last year or so. It is possible to write *excellent* questions about mathematics at all levels, and it is possible to write *poor* questions about mathematics at all levels. As a user, I want to see more of the former and less of the latter.

Comment: @Carl I am pretty sure that this time last year, people were lamenting the quality of the questions and claiming that they were not as good as they were a year ago...

Comment: @user1729 And correctly so. They also failed to act after lamenting, which is why a year later, they get to lament more.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: [Something like that](http://youtu.be/GWmGrR9a818?t=3m30s)? Are you The Hound?

Comment: @mixedmath: I vaguely remember that at some point meta decided that it is pretty impolite to dramatically edit the text of a post, which would include your "*really* edit" idea. But, I like the idea of *really* editing, and the notion that we should wait until the OP has abandoned the question strikes me as a good compromise. But I'm genuinely not sure of a heuristic by which I could measure "abandonment". I am prepared to say that 3mo without an edit is definitely enough, and the 59m edit I recently reverted is definitely not, but things sitting in the 30d scale feel awkward. Suggestions?

Comment: @EricStucky I'd begin by saying that since the past meta decisions landed the site where it is, they should not be taken as canon. My suggestion for the time scale: if the question has turned from [on-hold] to [closed], then the OP has failed to save it, and others can make their attempt. This happens five days after closing.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: The first order of business is to blame everything on the previous guy. I'd say that the dark ages landed the site where it is. Also the starting conditions of the universe and baryogenesis. Possibly strings, micro black holes (due to CERN experiments), Freemasons and Nazi pagan cults ceremonies to release ancient powers all had to do with it as well. More seriously, though, I don't think that we need to aggressively edit things written by other people; at least not "shortly after posting".

Comment: @AsafKaragila My first order of business has been to fix things. The blame game came about later, and from another source. Also, I am controlled by [signals from elsewhere](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2285484#2285484).

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: Shog didn't mention where. You picked the wrong site for it. In either case, yes, assigning blame to the predecessors did come later, but it's commutes with actually doing things, so without loss of generality it came first.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But that's the idea: pick a wrong site, and make it right.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: So your plan is to induce a collective Stockholm syndrome?

Comment: The concern I have is about your #2 "Once the question is closed, 3 10k users vote to delete." This is a way of a question being deleted even if it has a very highly scored answer. If you could find out how often this happens, compared to last year and update your post or reply to this comment I'd be grateful.

Comment: Since I have started using this SX regular, I have noticed that user don't vote nearly as much as the user on TeX which is small community.

Answer (score 11):

One suggestion.

A significant part (may be I'm projecting here?) of the sentiment against answering routine exercises is related to the fact that variants of the same exercise occur repeatedly. A few years back Bill Dubuque launched a campaign in favor of so called *abstract duplicates*: to have one sufficiently general umbrella Q/A prepared by an expert (or by community effort), and thereafter refer new entrants to that canonical answer (and otherwise close them on the spot). We have [a dedicated thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1868/11619) for collecting near-duplicates in Meta, but it is somewhat underused, and cannot really serve well to this end. Unfortunately the campaign for abstract duplicates has also fizzled since.

One of the suggested reasons to start our own [Stack Exchange Mathematics Blog](http://math.blogoverflow.com/) was that posts there might serve in this role.
That blog is in its infancy, and I have some doubts about how often visitors read it. 
Advertising the blog on the main site is a bit difficult. Anyway, the blog is one possible outlet for members with an overwhelming desire to teach. Right now the blog suffers from a shortage of material/authors. Together we could generate enough volume, which hopefully leads to more people reading it. This, hopefully, would in turn attract even more qualified people to contribute to the blog.

Comment: [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1868/72)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Elsewhere, there has been more than one insulting comment from you, so invitation declined.

Comment: My original post was [Coping with *abstract* duplicate question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242). To be sure, I'm not proposing that abstract dupe closing should always be done. Rather, I think decisions need to be made on a case-by-case basis, by users who have significant experience teaching the topic.

Comment: @Bill I guess it won't surprise you to hear that in my opinion your prophecy from 2011 has been fulfilled in the sense that meanwhile the problem **has gotten out of hand**, and the site has been swamped by hundreds of minor variations. Of course, the human answering machines turn the deaf ear to any suggestion of restraining their desire to show that "Look, I, too, can do this problem! Can I have my upvote, please!"

Comment: When I composed that post  I presumed that SE would evolve and develop good tools to handle dupes. But it hasn't - which posed major problems.. E.g. many of my answers link to other posts for proofs. If those posts end up being deleted because someone preferred another dupe thread then the proof link is left dangling. The ability to abstract and localize vias link (vs. duplicate inline) is paramount and should not be compromised. Just as for closures, many deletion votes are robotic, so overlook these matters (which take nontrivial time to assess).

Comment: I see your point, @Bill. I may want to see it as an argument in favor of deleting new duplicates and leaving the older versions. Anyway, it is something to keep in mind.  I keep referring people to your old answers (among other things). Mind you, I don't think any of the threads I used are in danger.

Comment: In the past I have mentioned this and other related issues (e.g. improper assessment of posts in merges) but, alas, the discussion is not easy to find by SE search tools. That's why I added the "delete" and "policy" tags to this old thread. Believe it or not someone sent a mod message to me about that. The mind boggles....

Answer (score 5):

Let me start off  by saying that I agree with the fact that this site should be as informative as possible, and that therefore each question should be of sufficient quality to be maintained. However, one should not forget that the main driver of this site is its users (and then especially a few high-rep users). Ideally, everyone would of course want the site to be 100% organized, but for obvious and legitimate reasons deleting questions that are of mediocre quality but that have high quality answers evokes negative emotions from exactly those high-rep users that are of such vital importance to this site. In an perfect world each question on the site is of high quality, but not being able to achieve this on every single question is always better than not having this site at all.

Now to respond to 900's latest answer in which he suggests that users edit questions which are at danger of being deleted, I have the following proposal: why does 900 (or any other person that sees a calling in upgrading the quality of the questions on this site) not edit those question himself instead of deleting them? I think this is the best compromise as it (a) satisfies high-rep users (and maintains their high quality answers) and (b) makes the questions on this site of higher quality.

Let us please try to put our personal differences aside and channel our energies into empowering this site, rather than to try to win personal battles.

Comment: Take a look at the [list of editors](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=quarter) for this quarter. Looks like I edited some things, doesn't it? But as [I said elsewhere](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/under-what-circumstances-is-it-appropriate-to-delete-a-question-that-has-receive#comment60300_16491): "them's the breaks: if I am the one picking up toys after kids had their fun, I get to decide whether a toy goes back on a shelf or to the dumpster. Those who want to make sure their toys avoid the dumpster should pick them up themselves."

Comment: "Let us please try to put our personal differences aside and channel our energies into empowering this site, rather than to try to win personal battles." What does "empowering this site" mean? And who is focused on personal battles rather than that?

Comment: How simple do you want me to put it for you: are you going to fill up the void if Andre Nicolas and/or Bill Dubuque would leave the site? You obviously seem to think that keeping this site clean is of more importance than keeping the users that make for the sole existence of this site.

Comment: Just a data point concerning "deleting questions [...] of mediocre quality but that have high quality answers": Since the [brouhaha began](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15126), I've gone to the "delete" tab in the 10K tools pretty much every day, and looked at a large part of the listed "Recently Deleted" questions (at least a dozen every time) to check if anything shouldn't have been deleted IMO. What I saw deleted was poor (or worse) questions with mediocre to somewhat goodish [and also with baddish] answers. There may be a few _good_ answers deleted, but that's tiny fraction.

Comment: @danielfisher If that is the case, then you have a valid point. But I honestly do think that Andre s OP is based on the fact that at least for him a significant amount of posts were deleted. And if this fraction is really so small, then why do we really still need to delete those posts, as their deletion evidently elicits so much commotion/frustration?

Comment: @jonasmeyer With 'personal battles' I was mainly referring to the fact that I sense that (a) the number of questions concerned is not that large (b) their deletion dissatisfied key members of this community (c) people are insisting to have them deleted rather than just editing those few posts. And that is what I mean with empowering this site: this issue is probably not worth all this fuzz around it and could simply be solved by editing those few questions; rather spend your time on other things.

Comment: @dreamer I have seen André's name not so often, but I may have just missed those. I don't know how many of his answers have been deleted. We would not need (and ordinarily should not, there may be exceptions) delete _good_ answers [then one should strive to make the question acceptable], but there are different views on what should count as good.

Comment: There was no need to down vote this. I respect peoples elaborate voting agendas - it makes this site the most respected SE - but a down vote shouldn't be considered unless the answer is particularly bad.

Comment: @Jyrkilahtonen I don't know enough of those statistics, but I trust thst you are right. My point is more that it seems that the number of questions that we are talking about does not seem to be that large that it would be an impossible task to just edit them. Is it really worth risking the departure of some of the most important members of this site for just that?

Comment: @dreamer: Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: What if failing to "keep the site clean" is "risking the departure of some of the most important members of this site" and effectively dis-empowering the site?

Comment: @did Failing to keep the site clean? As pointed out by Daniel Fisher, it concerns just a few questions here that have a *high quality answer*. Isn't it more than reasonable that the autors of these kind of answers don't want their posts to be deleted? That is not a matter of keeping the site clean, those few (from what I've heard, they are really just few) questions can simply be salvaged by editing them. Keeping the site clean is a matter of filtering out large numbers of low quality posts, not deleting questions with proper answers.

Comment: @dreamer maybe I have missed something, but noone is claiming that the deleted answers of Andre were good! Indeed, only one of his answer's is linked to in this thread, and it was as an example of a *bad* answer. Evidence...give me evidence...

Comment: (But I should say that I agree that editing is preferable to deleting, so +1)

Comment: Dreamer, you are welcome to start editing. I'm sure that 900 would appreciate all the help he can get. Also it's not his fault that Bill and André have answered crappy questions (as have I). The blame belongs to the lazy OPs (and the FGITWs whose rapid answers in some way legitimize the sloppy questions).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The questions that we are talking about were apparently of at least enough quality to be answerable, hence also to be salvegable. I personally don't feel the urge to improve all those questions, I'm just saying that for those who do I find deletion of the questions rather improper. People might have put a lot of work into writing answers, so if you really feel the need to make the question of higher quality then, then you should edit, not delete.

Comment: @user1729 I cannot say that I have seen any examples myself either, but should the user with the most reputation on this site really defend himself by showing examples? I trust Andre Nicolas. What incentive would he have to lie about this?

Comment: Dreamer, I think that you are misplacing the burden. Anyway, here's [one example of what salvaging a question may entail](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/780997/11619). The OP used odd notation, and the question was quickly put on hold as *unclear*. I felt differently. I generated and added two animations to explain what the question was about. It was duly reopened shortly. But that was well over an hour of work. I only answered it much later. Anyway, it is unreasonable to expect that kind of salvage effort hundreds of times per month. And all that so that your heros could bask in the glory.

Comment: (cont'd) Mind you, that question does also exhibit the trigger happy nature of close voting. The problem in the first place was caused by a retiree using idiosyncratic notation. The context he lucidly described only allowed for a single interpretation that made sense, so any mathematician who would stop to think about it would have given the same interpretation I did. Anyway, my point is that salvaging a wrecked question is often more work than answering it well would be. I don't have any illusions of superiority. I'm sure several members could have given the answer I gave.

Comment: @dreamer I do not think that has mentioned the word "good" either. Noone is lying - Andre is frustrated that he is loosing posts, while 900 et. al claim that these posts were no loss to the site (that they were not very good).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In this specific case you are absolutely right that the effort involved to fix the question might have been unreasonably high. But to generalize this to all questions? I still believe that most questions do not require such tremendous efforts to be fixed; and that if they have a high quality answer then I'd rather have them remain.

Comment: @user1729 How often have you seen Andre Nicolas give answers that were not *good*?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen To speak with your words: you are one of those 'hero's' of this site. I cannot possibly imagine that you would want a large batch of your answers deleted solely for the sake of not having a few questions on the site that are not of very high quality.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That is indeed the essence of the discussion. I understand that you do not have such a thing as copyright of your answers on this site, but nonetheless the emotion prevails that these are *my* (in this case Andre's) answers, and that someone else, without knowing anything of how much time they might have cost to write down, simply deletes them (for obscure reasons).

Comment: @dreamer Be careful with such questions! Because I do not think I have ever met Andre on main. Also, he is prolific enough that my seeing 1 bad question would be a significant number of questions (as anyone is unlikely to have read more than 100, say, of his questions).

Comment: @user1729  ;) Ok, I think you get the idea though, I believe most of his posts at least are of high quality and that his frustration does not come out of nowhere.

Comment: @dreamer I do not know whether most of his posts are of high quality, *however* there is still an underlying assumption that the deleted posts are good....and we have still not overcome this assumption.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I assumed in good faith that for Andre in this case a few of those answers that he cared about (like the ones you mentioned for yourself) were deleted. I can agree with you that not all answers are such that they really have to be maintained, but like I said I trust Andre that he did not start this thread for little reason. I must say that your answer to the question you linked was nice btw ;)

Comment: @user1729 I base that assumption on the experience that I have with his answers. And again, what incentive would he have to lie about this?

Comment: @Jyrki If the primary concern is that not deleting poor questions leaves examples that might motivate further poor questions then the solution is simple: instead of deleting the question insert a big bold banner at the top saying that this question is considered to be very poor quality etc so that any new users who stumble upon it will have no doubt that questions like that will likely be closed. As a benefit, the banner can link to the faq topic on how to ask a a good question, which will provide plenty of good free advertising for the FAQ, possibly improving general question quality.

Comment: @Bill: Make sure you account for [user myopia](http://blog.codinghorror.com/treating-user-myopia/) in your expectations. (this note doesn't mean to suggest it's a bad idea, just that we shouldn't expect a large fraction of people to really pay attention)

Comment: @BillDubuque Putting such a banner on top of question, with an answer underneath it, would be saying: "You shouldn't ask such questions, but if you do, we'll answer anyway".

Comment: @900 No the idea is that the banner would relay the information that, while such questions were answered in the past, when majority opinions were different, nowadays they are likely to be *very* quickly closed as off-topic, long before any answers can appear (or somesuch). Not that I agree with such policies. But this alleviates the need to delete the good answers due to your "broken question" argument.

Comment: @900 But I think a better solution is to have a meta thread listing "bad" questions with "good" answers that are proposed to be preserved. This would give users a chance to edit and improve the question so to preserve the good answers, which seems like a reasonable compromise. But we would need a more efficient way to locate these. Perhaps with the help of some of your scripts?

Answer (score -2):

[Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) explains:

> #### Answer well-asked questions
>
> Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...
>
> - ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.
> - ...solicit opinions rather than facts.
> - ...have already been asked and answered many times before.
> - ...require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions.
> - ...are not about math as defined in the help center.

Let's take [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/875210/) as an example: it's a recent one;  I voted to close, and it's my downvote on the answer there.

1. The question is unclear: there is no assumption of $X$ and $Y$ being independent, and without that there isn't a way to find joint PMF.
2. There is no indication of what the asker has difficulty with.
3. "Find joint PMF" questions have been asked and answered many times before, even [with exactly the same parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/538782/)

Some of these issues could be fixed. The Help Center says:

> Don't forget that you can edit the question you're answering to improve the clarity and focus - this can reduce the chances of the question being closed or deleted.

The independence assumption, the all-caps BINOMIAL, the incorrect [statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) tag -- those things could be fixed, but ... that's a kind of boring task best left to others.

In a nutshell, there is a contradiction between

1. *I want to answer any question I feel like answering, regardless of its quality*.
2. *I want my answers to be preserved on the site.*

On Stack Exchange, you get to pick one, not both.

Comment: In my opinion, your massive crusade of downvoting and deleting helpful answers is *by far* the most nonconstructive behavior that has ever occurred in the 4 year lifetime of MSE. As is clear from this thread (and others), your behavior is *greatly* alienating some of the best teachers on this site. Is that what you desire?

Comment: And why should we care about some random text in the "Help Center"? Was that authored by our users (esp. experienced teachers?) No, it was not, so it has little chance or pertaining to the major issues MSE faces.

Comment: Although @Bill and I have vastly differing philosophies on closures, I agree with him that the scale of this crusade of deletions is beyond destructive, having now affected (by your count) over three thousand posts. However, I seem to recall you left a comment in a related thread whose punchline was "I don't care, and will continue doing this no matter the backlash," so I'm probably wasting my time by commenting here.

Comment: It is a bit off-topic here but since it was brought up by @BillDubuque once again: the amount of poor-quality questions and related phenomena is extremely off putting for some others.

Comment: I also think it's worth pointing out that this post makes absolutely no attempt to answer the question, which is about sites similar to MSE. Its only purpose seems to be to tell André that he's wrong to answer the questions he answers and expect his contributions not be deleted. (-1).

Comment: @T.Bongers: If there are three thousand questions that should be deleted, then what is the problem with someone deleting those three thousand questions?

Comment: @Hurkyl, I think the problem is that some of those delete-worthy questions have attracted keep-worthy answers. Deleting the question throws the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: @Hourly I don't oppose question deletions in general, and I've been involved in hundreds of those.  But it shouldn't be left up to this one user's unilateral campaign with no community consensus or oversight.

Comment: @Gerry: I agree that's probably what was actually meant by the opposition. But since T. specifically cited *scale* as the reason for opposition, so I'd like to hear how that works if that's what he really means. (or if not, have it corrected to something like "I have always disagreed with deletions, and the scale means I can't simply ignore it any longer" or whatever actual thing is accurate)

Comment: @Hurkyl I object to the scale because it's being carried out by one user only. A big reason I participate in Mae is its democratic nature. Good answers are being lost due to one user's actions.

Comment: @T.: Then oversee! Shine a spotlight on what's *actually* happening, so that the community can do some oversight. Maybe I haven't paid enough attention to meta, but all of the objections to this campaign I've seen have been on matters of principle (and, IMO, with blinders on). I haven't noticed anyone doing something like dredging up a representative sample of deleted posts so that the community can discuss their opinions about their fates, or cherry picking some outliers that probably shouldn't have been deleted but wound up being collateral damage.

Comment: @T.Bongers From [900's profile:](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/147263/900-sit-ups-a-day) "$4300\!+$ downvotes on Math (site record), of them $3500\!+$ on now-deleted posts.
$2200\!+$ votes to close on Math, of them $1300\!+$ on now-deleted posts". So it seems he is quite proud of this destructive behavior over $3$ month's time. What a sad state of affairs.

Comment: @Hurkyl I did shine a light, and my last meta post is at plus 32 complaining about this user's actions.  Nothing changed.  Perhaps I'll write up another post tonight with specific examples.

Comment: @T.: Ah, that's right, you *did* post some examples in that. I had forgotten, since the meta question as asked wasn't about "should these be deleted". (and the examples all seemed unremarkable things that I would lean towards "yes, they should be")

Comment: @Hurkyl I posted a question [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/under-what-circumstances-is-it-appropriate-to-delete-a-question-that-has-receive), sans examples - I phrased it about the abstract question.

Comment: @T.Bongers *no attempt to answer the question* -- the "question" is a flimsy pretext to post the half-rant, half-threat labeled "Introduction", and I responded to that.

Comment: @T.: Okay, and it's a fine question, but oversight would require actually looking at the things being deleted. (maybe the abstract question is in preparation for later looking at concrete examples?)

Comment: @BillDubuque "...greatly alienating some of the best teachers on this site." The implication here is that high reputation implies good teacher (because this question is focused on a high-rep user). I do not know if this implication is what you meant, however I do not believe it to be true. High reputation implies prolific teacher, but I am sure that many of the best teachers on this site wile away their time on their favourite tags, barely breaching 20K. Prolific does not imply good...

Comment: There is also the implication that stopping the behavior that Bill complains would not greatly alienate some of the best teachers on the site, nor would it greatly alienate some of the best teachers who would otherwise have joined the site.

Comment: @Hurkyl Or left this site already! (Citing a recent dig-up.)

Comment: @user1729 There is no such implication. The passage you quote is a remark I make in *many* threads. It most certainly does *not* imply that I believe that high rep is correlated with good teaching skills (it makes no mention of rep). In fact, perhaps more than anyone, I often emphasize that rep is little correlated to *anything.* Further I've supported both teachers whose methods I agree with and those that I strongly disagree with (including one high rep user who recently left). So there is no logical basis to your speculations. Ditto to Hurkyl. Please strive for *logically sound* arguments!

Comment: @Bill I have noticed you make this claim before, and I have then also wondered about this underlying implication. I felt that the implication here was clear enough to comment, so thank you for clarifying. *However*, it is still an entirely unsubstantiated claim. I do not feel that you could ever back it up, as Hurkyl will always be able to give the reply he has given. We will never know which option would be best for the site. Rather than quoting anonymously, etc, can simply speak for yourself. Which carries weight.

Comment: @Bill: The logical basis for my speculations is the presumption *you* have a *logically sound argument* in mind, rather than, for example, just making an emotional appeal with words like "nonconstructive" and one-sided laments about the (alleged) problems with one course of action.

Comment: @Hurkyl I can make no sense of either of your prior comments. It is rather sad that logically unsound arguments are now par for the course on meta. I expected better in a forum whose members have studied mathematics.

Comment: @bill: Not that I have any expectation you'll listen, but.... You say that 900 is greatly alienating some of the best teachers on the site. ***So what?*** You haven't made a thesis statement, or an argument connecting your claim to your thesis statement. Any actual meaning you might have is left to an unspoken implication. Among the most obvious implications of your words is that 900's course of action will alienate more people than not following that course of action will. If you did not mean that, then I'm quite comfortable laying all the blame for miscommunication upon you.

Comment: @Bill: Funny, I could say exactly the same thing towards you. :P Have you at least noticed the *irony* of your previous comment?

Comment: @Hurkyl Don't expect any further responses to logically unsound nonsense - none will be forthcoming.