# I found 3 questions asking about an ongoing contest.

Tags: discussion, contests

The following 3 questions were asked and are part of an ongoing contest: https://iymc.info/data/Pre-Final-Round-Problems-2018-x3285s7f2.pdf

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

I did not realize this yesterday, but upon going through the Pre-Final round problems, I discovered a user posting the problems here, violating their policy: "*It is not allowed to work in groups on the problems. Help or assistance from teachers, friends, family, or the internet is prohibited. Cheating will result in immediate disqualification!*"

I have reported this to both the relevant authorities and flagged for moderator intervention. One of them is unanswered, another has two wrong hints that can easily be corrected while the last is shown to be unsolved. I would like to request fellow users to not answer the questions till after 5th of November, 2018; the last day of submission. Thank you!

---

**Edit 1)**

I have just received a response from the organizers of the event:

> "Thank you for your message and the information. This is unacceptable behavior, thank you for reporting this incident - you accomplished a great feat for enabling a fair competition. Please continue helping the IYMC community by reporting these incidents if they continue to emerge. IYMC tries its best to tackle people and behavior that try to sabotage the competition - the help of our community is essential for that."

The very fact that they managed to reply to the complaint in 2 hours is a commendable feat and their dedication to keep the competition as fair as possible is amazing.

---

**Edit 2)**

As a fellow user in the comments pointed out, another question is also from the same competition:

[image: 5]

I have repeated my previous actions and would like to sincerely thank user @md2perpe for pointing it out as I had not noticed that particular question before.

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I've voted to close the questions that were still open and left comments suggesting answerers to delete their answers.

Comment: I deleted the three questions for now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That works too :)

Comment: @Asaf As far as I know, there's another way to deal with ongoing contest questions: lock the question until the deadline.  Why did you delete them instead?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: I was in a bit of a rush to leave the house, and deleting is significantly faster. I'll also note that we sometimes delete contests questions as well. In this case it seemed a bit more appropriate too, since at least on some of them there were hints given in the comments too.

Comment: @Asaf Thx for reply and explanation !  I agree that's nicer and quicker than deleting each comment and locking the question.

Comment: We occasionally get posts here at meta, alerting us to an ongoing contest, so we can know what to look out for. It would have been good to get such a warning for this contest, before all these posts showed up. Anyway, my apologies for having helped out on the "relatively many primes" question.

Comment: Well, I did notice one person using this site for the Qualification round but that did not violate the contest policy for that round. My apologies, but anyway, the final round will not be online so that should help.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 We have always been hiding the answers (by deleting them) of locked contest question until the contest deadline has passsed. There used to be a mod-only chatroom where we collected links to such questions together with their deadlines. Checking out that room was not always done in timely fashion, so undeletion may have been tardy. But it did help because we didn't need to rely on memory alone. I don't know if the current mod team still uses that room.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So only 10k users can view them?  I hope this is enough to stop ongoing contest question askers.

Comment: They can still use private chats or ask their elder siblings. Worse is when their parents or teachers help them.

Comment: I have attended to the first problem above, a mistake. I shall be more careful in the future.

Comment: Calm down all. 1) I'm not sure that suspensions help here. People with throwaway accounts just create new ones (and blocking an IP is slower and should IMHO only be on the cards after several offences). 2) I once got in touch with a contest organizer, apologizing that I was not allowed to disclose the offender's e-mail address and such. They appeased me by telling that *We have no trouble whatsoever identifying copycat entrants as such :-)*

Comment: @Jyrki: Case in point, the account on those questions has been self-deleted already.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг You had no way of knowing that it was a contest-question instead of a PSQ.

Comment: Another question from this contest: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980930/find-a-function-wx-such-that-the-function-fx-sinwx-has-the-roots-at

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @md2perpe !

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: That's one good reason to not answer PSQs, because cheaters are often lazy.

Comment: If you notice my edit $2$, the user did a perfect execution but got stuck at the final stage. I personally took a different route but both work.

Comment: Thank you for TeXing the $3$.

Comment: @Randall I am not quite sure what you mean by that???

Comment: Just a random idea, but it should be possible to use approach0 parsing technology and set up kind of alarms in cases like this - set of expressions that are automatically monitored for given period of time and potential alarm triggered in case they occur, so a human can check. It wouldn't be always useful, but in this case the expressions in the competition are quite specific.

Comment: Perhaps the first time a user uses the contest-math tag it should specify that problems from ongoing contests is unacceptable and violates site policy. Might not be very effective but can reduce the number of such questions on this site

Comment: @Raptor except that there is no such policy. We only close them temporarily as a courtesy. There is no rule on the books about this. MSE has no obligation to prevent cheating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Contest problem" policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy)

Comment: @Harald, this is more like informing the users of the breach of site policy. If you would notice, I did indeed follow the contest problem policy.

Comment: @Harald no because that question does not actual enforce this breach. Meta is to inform as much as discuss. This specific issue was not discussed. Regardless that post is 4 years old. We should rediscuss the policy.

Comment: OT: Please don't use MathJax for the digits in things like "has asked 3 questions", "edit 2:", etc. These are not math. Typesetting them as such looks bad.

Comment: I always had the feeling the majority of the questions here were University level tutorial questions.. But asking ongoing competition questions here is the next level XD

Comment: The deadline was over 17 hours ago. Reopen the questions?

Comment: [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980930/find-a-function-wx-such-that-the-function-fx-sinwx-has-the-roots-at) is still closed.

Comment: You should raise the issue in the CRUDE chatroom

Comment: StackOverflow officer @animuson has edited this question, writing "Please do not focus on specific users in meta questions". But it's an important part of this question that it was one specific user posting all three questions from the ongoing contest, as it speaks to a systematic effort by that user to use our website to subvert the contest. I call on animuson to revert to the previous version (as there is no option for ordinary users to rollback these edits).

Comment: @GerryMyerson We do not allow meta questions which focus on specific users' behavior. If something cannot be discussed without focusing on a user, then it is not an appropriate discussion for meta.

Comment: @animuson thank you for the edit and my apologies as this only my second meta question.

Comment: @animuson except it's a meta question *and* a report to the community. Changing the wording of the post hardly changes that it is obvious from 3 screenshots which user was posting these problems. The question itself focuses on the user simply by product of saying which questions reference the contest....

Comment: This could easily be resolved if we pin these questions up.

Comment: Content apart, do you really need $\mathrm{MathJax}\;\mathrm{for}\;\mathrm{numbers}$ in the post?

Comment: My apologies, removed @Mr.Z

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it is indeed despicable if someone takes part in a contest and cheats in this way, I am surprised everyone seems to agree that questions should be closed and accounts should be blocked. But calm down.

When I look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I don't see a regulation that says: don't post contest questions if it is not allowed by the rules of the contest.

If the questions deserve a close on their own merit, or lack of, they should of course be closed. (I did not look at the examples).

If the user's behavior deserves blocking the account, they should be blocked. But given that there are no rules against posting contest questions, on which base do you want to block them --- apart from the feeling they're doing something wrong.

As an additional thought: consider the teacher at a high school hands out an exam about Goethe. To test what the pupils have learned and not what they are able to quickly look up on Wikipedia, Wikipedia lookup is not allowed during the exam. Should Wikipedia be informed up-front and block the page about Goethe?

Should math.SE really police every math contest around world? How do you make sure not to block the wrong questions or users, someone not taking part in the contest, being just curious and not realizing the contest is ongoing? Someone by mere accident asking a question similar to what is needed in the contest.

My suggestion would be to explicitly define contest questions off-topic while the contest is running and, as proposed, block the question until the contest is over, if flagged respectively. A user violating this rule repeatedly can then be blocked/suspended based simply by applying the rules.

Comment: Interesting proposition. Perhaps you should ask this as a separate question on meta?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your suggestion is actually the policy that is generally applied.

Comment: Harald, I disagree. We have [a very clear policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16774/11619). We cannot have all the policies described in the Help Center. There's no room there. Discard the notion that policies should be written there, please. META is the place were policies are discussed, formulated, posted, refined and updated.

Comment: Didn't know that. But that means the current question should be marked as a duplicate of that policy question. Will flag accordingly.

Comment: Despite my support for [Math.SE]'s ongoing contest policy, I don't think that we have to police around the world's math contests.  Instead, we'll act passively upon notification of suspected ongoing contest questions.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Sigh. That is beyond our control. It's been explained iin meta umpteen times that *Off-topic -> missing context* really only means *missing context*. Search the meta for the reason. Contest questions mostly are  *on-topic* (but may be lacking in context).

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Did you somehow miss the oft repeated fact that if we have a customed close reason, for reasons dictated by the SE software, that reason can only exist under *off-topic*. Not ideal, granted, but beating a dead horse.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Um no, I had not heard that at all, ever. However, I was thinking of something that could be added to the SE site in general since the issue of contests and cheating goes far beyond MSE. However, the odds of that happening I suppose depend on how often the SE infrastructure gets updated.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Here is [a response from SE staff](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28826/11619) to the latest feature request from Math.SE.