# Why is this question off-topic

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question, context

I have been following [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505363/geo-angle-bisectors). It has recently been marked as *off-topic*. I have checked the requirements for being [on/off-topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but they don't seem to apply to this question. Can someone please explain why this is off-topic?

**Note.** I know that OP is a new contributor, and he or she probably didn't explain the question in the best way, but I think that it is a decent math problem and on-topic.

Comment: To add a bit more details, the stated close reason is: "This question is missing context or other details: Please [provide additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc." It was [suggested before](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26524) that it might be better to have this separately - not under off-topic.

Comment: 1) Thanks for the link to the off-topic discussion. I wasn't aware of that. 2) How can you see the close reason? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: In the banner it says: "Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege." Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jjeu.png
This could explain why some users see this information and some don't.
AFAICT this was changed relatively recently, see these posts on [meta.se]:
[New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700) and
[New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013).