# The "Private feedback for you" message.

Tags: support, closed-questions

Some of my questions have been closed. A box appears with the title "Closed". In it the message "Private feedback for you" appears. In my email box no message from Stack Overflow appears. Is this message readable in some link in the closed thread page?

Comment: There should be some text below  the "Private feedback for you" or maybe  a link you can click. That text is the feedback, it is not personalized but if you look at the same post while not logged in (open eg a "private" browser window you'll see the difference). No email or other message is sent.

Comment: There is no text below. Only two links: 'Edit question' and 'Delete question'!

Comment: The answer explains which text is meant.

Comment: @quid: 'There should be some text below the "Private feedback for you"': The text is _above_ it, not below. The answer explains nothing. Nothing at all.

Comment: Indeed it is above, sorry for the confusion. The answer post here points out exactly what text is meant.

Comment: The answer is: "The "private feedback" for this question is the (rather obvious)

    Some community members have associated this post with a similar question". It should be "The "private feedback" for this question is the (rather obvious) text

    Some community members have associated this post with a similar question". Or, yet better: "The "private feedback" for this question is the following text:

    Some community members have associated this post with a similar question".

.

Answer (score 6):

The "private feedback" for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3509301/228959) is the (rather obvious)

> Some community members have associated this post with a similar question.

If you open the question in a private window, or in another browser where you're not logged in, you'll see this:

[image]

That banner doesn't include the 'private' part of the feedback, only shown to you and to other users with 3,000 reputation:

[image]

For a question closed as a duplicate, it isn't particularly helpful, but for community-specific ('off-topic') questions it might provide some guidance to improving the question so that it can be reopened.

This is a change in behaviour which was introduced in December of 2019. For more information, see the Meta Stack Exchange post [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/295232) and linked questions/blog posts there, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/05/new-post-notices-improving-feedback-on-stack-overflow-questions/).

Comment: This question (on this meta) has also some screenshots and comments: [New changes to close reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31544).

Comment: Just as remark about the "Private feedback" message is that I don't understand how works it: my belief is that when I am not logged in the site (I've observed the same thing in other site) and I visit some post that was marked as closed but previously also was edited I believe that can to know why was closed and who cast these votes by clicking in the link `edited ...` below the post . For example the mentioned information is public when you do click in `edited Jul 20 at 21:40` from the post https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32115/2020-moderator-election-qa-question-collection