# Handling answers that don't answer the question

Tags: discussion, flagging, answers

Often times, I come across "answers" that are related to the question but don't answer the question that has actually been asked in the OP. Often times this occurs when the OP asks for an explanation of a proof, or how to finish a proof, and the answer gives an entirely unrelated proof. [The example has been deleted because it's not an actual example, see comments for discussion]

I usually downvote such answers and leave a comment explaining why, but it occurred to me that such an answer might be flaggable as "not an answer." Is that an appropriate action? Is that a better way to disincentive users who have a high frequency of answers like this than just downvoting them?

Note that this is not a listed reason [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81389/when-should-you-decide-whether-to-flag-a-posted-answer-as-not-an-answer/81392#81392) and is arguably discouraged [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag).

Comment: The stream of b--s answers by this OP is going on for quite some time now, so much so that it has become a specific problem which the mods, for reasons I cannot fathom, refuse to act upon.

Comment: People with [deletion privileges](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) might want to consider using them on highly downvoted posts.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Some of them do, indeed, but the stream continues unabated... :-( There has to be a shortcut to the ever repeating cycle BSA posted / BSA downvoted / BSA deleted / three new BSAs posted in the mean time.

Comment: @Did, normally, somebody *reasonable* who's racked up a sizable amount of downvoted/deleted posts would pause to consider what s/he might be doing wrong. It is unfortunate that we are not seeing that sort of people here.

Comment: (At this juncture, I'd like to remind users with deletion privileges that looking at [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days) might be useful. Some of the entries there have apparently lasted more than two months.)

Comment: I have been observing the user for quite a while, yes. :) I've done my part in voting to delete some of the... less useful of the lot. I brought up the thing on deletion precisely because I think we're *supposed* to have [a sizable amount of people with deletion privileges](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?page=8&tab=reputation&filter=all).

Comment: Well, you'll have one more in the ranks in a month or so.

Comment: @Stella While said user does have many answers worthy of deletion, this one most surely **does answer the OP's question**, viz. "Is there an easier way to prove this?". Gerry Myerson even emphasized this is in a comment. So it is a particularly poor example to use to make your point. Nor does it deserve to be deleted or so heavily downvoted. This seems to be an extreme example of history-motivated robovoting. Not exactly something that one should be highlighting. To reverse this nonsense,  I have voted to undelete it, as should any reasonable user.

Comment: @BillDubuque It's virtually the same proof provided in the OP, with less explanation. I suppose you could say that using $2$ instead of $3$ is an innovation, but I am highly skeptical of such a claim.

Comment: @Stella It's certainly not the same, since the OP's proof says nothing at all about the parity of exponents in prime factorizations.

Comment: @BillDubuque You're right. The two are tied in my head, but there's no particular reason to assume the OP thinks like that, and they're not explicitly tied together. I'll remove the link to the question and search for a better example tomorrow. I'll also comment on the answer when it gets undeleted.

Comment: @Bill, to be fair, I only left that comment *after* reading the current post.

Comment: I'm not having the greatest of weeks, so may be I should shut up, but my suggested remedy once was outlined [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16484/11619) - Declare questions answerable by a call to a CAS (or Wolfram Alpha) **OFF-TOPIC**. Yes, we lose some teaching opportunities, but we also get rid of tons of crap.

Comment: On another note, I am open to suggestions. The diamond mods asked SE staff about our options, and the answer was that we have no special way of constraining DrG. We can suspend the user (he was suspended once already), but under what rule? Causing disturbance? That might be warranted, but can also be a can of worms.

Comment: But community moderation is the option open to all. Downvote, vote to delete et cetera. It won't lead to a post-ban for this user because he is too high rep (a consequence of inviting many users who appreciate copy/pastable answers), but sends a strong signal.

Comment: I've spent mega time voting to close, or commenting on, or deleting this user's answer posts;  but I've had to spend time, occasionally, in calling out clearly offensive posts directed to said user, which attack the person, but not the problem.  Offensive posts are offensive, and they are no less offensive for the particular user we all know.  If people restrained themselves to only pointing out what exactly the errors are, or downvoting and/or voting  to delete, without personally attacking the user with sophomoric or sarcastic words, the restraint will be worth it.

Comment: I agree with @JyrkiLahtonen that community moderation is the best vehicle to use to try to alter the behavior.  And I do support Jyrki's [proposal, too](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16484/11619), particularly if it becomes adopted over time as the community norm.

Comment: Just, please don't publicly attack any one specific user in meta, especially when there is not longer a reference to the person and/or answer the asker here was talking about in the first place.  None of the comments make much sense with that connection edited out.  The only give-away is the reference to DrG. At the very least, when there is a witch-hunt or warlock-hunt, extend the decency to at least notify the target so she/he can respond to the attacks.

Comment: I'm really terribly sorry that this has become/been interpreted as a personal attack on that user. I did not even know about this context when I made this post.

Comment: I didn't direct my comment to you, Stella. No worries. Others just ran with the opportunity to vent about the user.  Your post was fine, and it was likely good to have removed the post in question, subsequently; other users simply ran with it, and never seemed to answer your more general question.  No worries, Stella!

Comment: I agree with @amWhy; while downvoting and deletion is fine, rudeness is not. I have seen not a few mean comments that could use some reining in before.

Comment: Stella, you've done nothing wrong. The problem you brought up is something that needs to be addressed. Not surprisingly this particular user has been discussed in meta earlier. Props for posting (and editing out the link to the not most convincing Exhibit A)

Comment: The exact identity of the user being vilified isn't really relevant, @Santropedro.  It's a sad example of this community's tendency to, every once in awhile, target specific users. Sort of like a public stoning, and particularly here in meta.  I think it would have been better for all concerned to talk about problematic behaviors and handling answers that don't answer questions, because there are many users whose answers have failed to answer questions.  The only reason I'm not disclosing the user's identity, is because I'm not here to shame anyone.  But thanks for your comment!

Comment: I've definitely downvoted and reported the user in question a lot. They are helpful at times, but outright unhelpful, misleading, or ineffectual at others. There are a handful of users like this, and I wish there was something we could do, but.. community policing is probably the best option, unfortunately. One good thing about this user is that it brought this issue to my attention, and I've become much less forgiving of poor answers and questions overall.

Answer (score 5):

Say I am trying to prove a certain theorem. The attempt has bogged down in a technical snarl-up, at which point I ask for help. Suppose that the helper, instead of solving the snarl-up, bypasses it by directly proving the theorem in a neat way. Do I thank the helper for enlightening me? Or do I complain that the provided proof does not untangle the mess I created? Even if I were the latter sort of person, I would find it hard to argue that the provided proof has done harm, or that its provider should be punished for it.

Comment: It depends what one wants. If I want to prove a theorem and what I care about is whatever proof,  my question ought to be  for a proof of it. (My attempt or ideas would be provided as context and potential help to askers.) If what I want is a specific form of proof and I say say so clearly; and somebody provides a different one, then this person would not have answered my question. That said, it is true that some askers get this wrong when phrasing their questions. This is commonly referred to as [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: Now suppose I'm the third person, who didn't ask the question nor write the answer. I probably came to that page for just that sort of answer. Do I support it, having gained new insights? Or do I punish it for not answering someone else's problem?

Answer (score 1):

The example has been deleted and I mostly read answers on this site (so I've done no moderation and have no particular interest in rule pages). That said, I think sites like these should always cast a very wide net on what's acceptable as an answer, simply because the audience for any given answer is way larger than just the OP. People who come around with a similar question but not enough time/interest/whatever to ask a whole new question often get key info from answers that are merely related to what the OP asked. The OP gets to mark their answer; let that be enough for them.

I pretty much only downvote things on StackExchange sites that I can't imagine anyone finding useful. Completely wrong answers are just the most prominent example.