# Questions being reported as duplicates despite the "duplicate" being a generalization to the other

Tags: discussion, closing, exact-duplicates, close-reasons

I am a second year math student and a fairly new user of this page so there's still a lot of things I don't understand both in the site and about maths. This is why I tend to ask a lot of questions as I feel like the users here are understanding of the fact my knowledge is not advanced and like to help people like me understand things better.

However, a problem I have faced with the last couple of questions I have asked here is that many of them get closed as duplicates and the post I get redirected to answers just a specific case of my original question.

Whenever this happens to me, my first instinct is to think that my question is in fact a duplicate and that I might be missing some detail onto why this two questions are the same. However, as it has happened more and times I can't help but to think that oftentimes questions are closed either too early or without an understanding of the details in them.

I was wondering whether this was a common ocurrence on this site or if it's a problem only on my questions (maybe from poor explaining as english is not my first language).

*As an example of what I mean here is a link to my latest question where I ask about GCD domains and it gets reported as a duplicate of a post that answers my question but only for integers (a much more specific case)* [Divisors in GCD domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456550/divisors-in-gcd-domain?noredirect=1#comment9334819_4456550)

Comment: I have experienced the same thing. Close-voters do not always appreciate the nuances of a question.

Comment: Yeah I think a lot of the time people are senselessly closing questions. They do not read the question even and just see title , text, number of close voter and be like "lets slam the close vote button". I was sort of like this at some point, then I realize closing as dupe is really an ineffective strategy and does pretty much nothing for the site unless a certain question is a dupe of an old question with a great answer. Then for saving time of people revisiting that question the new new one can be closed as dupe of old one. However, even then, it is sometime not clear what shuld be closed ..

Comment: as dupe of what. Because sometimes, the newer question has much better presentation than the new one. I think maybe this close by dupe feature should be replaced as a 'merging' feature so any new answer will be brought into old one. The person who asked question first time ever get all rep of even new question. No negative reprecussion to person who posted new dupe either

Comment: In your GCD question, the linked proofs in the dupe **work in any gcd domain** - hence the duplicate closure. If this is not clear to you then please ask questions on the linked dupe (that will help improve the answer if need be). You should always ask such questions *before* posting to meta. See also [abstract duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242).

Comment: @Bill has mentioned two of the things you can do in your situation; you can try to understand why your question really is a duplicate (that is, how the argument at the old question can be adapted to answer your question), and if you're not convinced you can ask at the old question how it applies to your question. If that doesn't work out for you, the third thing you can do is try to convince users that your question is not a duplicate. We have a thread dedicated to just such requests.

Comment: I too a quick look at your other 4 questions closed as dupes and they too appear to be proper dupe closures. That many of your recent questions are dupes indicates that you should strive to spend more time searching for answers before posting your questions.

Comment: Funnily, I only had to look at the question title in the Hot Meta Posts banner and knew exactly who would have closed questions as duplicates. :-)

Comment: Keep in mind that while the **question** linked might not be as general as yours, that quite often some **solutions** are more general than the question asked for, and so your question really might have a solution there already.  It doesn't make any sense in that case to dismiss better-than-necessary answers just because they had the bad luck of appearing on a more specific question.  I don't know if this happened in your case but it is quite possible.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani In fact that are 3 different users involved in his 5 recent duplicate closures (I closed only one of them  - the example he gave above). But, as I said above, they all appear to be proper dupe closures.

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks for the help. I wasn't looking for any of my questions to get reopened, I just felt like the questions I got redirected to didn't quite answer mine but I was't sure whether that was my issue for not knowing enough. One thing I didn't know though was that people still answer questions asked in older posts so thats really helpful to know.

Comment: @MikelSolaguren If it is not clear how the cited linked answers apply to your question then you can ask for elaboration, either by a comment addressing a closer on your original question, and/or by comments on the linked answers(s). If none of that helps then you can repost your question with addition context elaborating in detail why the linked answers did not help you (without such elaboration it will likely again be closed as a dupe).

Comment: I feel that most often, questions are closed before I have the opportunity to explain, as the said, the "nuances of a question". I think it would be nice to leave a comment asking for clarifications before closing a question.

Comment: I would like to offer this as an example of a question that should not have been closed, in my opinion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460630/is-there-a-general-solution-for-gcd-problems-in-for-of-if-gcda-b-1-then?noredirect=1#comment9345165_4460630

Comment: I think some of what @Gerry and Bill are trying to convey, is that this site works best when askers and answerers are active participants in the Q&A format.  That is why we expect context from askers, and a willingness to do a bit more work, or clarify (Gary summarizes this very well) just as we expect answerers not not regularly answer low quality, or questions they should reasonably know are duplicates.